# Login PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, md5

Im new to PHP and i'm trying to make a login form so People can Login with their email and password.

The password and email is in my database. The password is md5 encrypted.

Currently, when I go to the form, it is working. However, when I click connect, it goes to my includes/login.php and it get stucks in a white page.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $user = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $passmd5 = md5($pass);
    include('connexiondb.php');
    $check = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM User WHERE EmailUser == $user');
    while($checkRow = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
        $passmd5db = $checkRow['PassUser'];
        $accessUser = $checkRow['AccessUser'];
        $idUser = $checkRow['IDUser'];
    }
    if($passmd5 == $passmd5db) {    
        // dans ce cas, tout est ok, on peut démarrer notre session

        // on la démarre :)
        session_start ();
        // on enregistre les paramètres de notre visiteur comme variables de session ($login et     $pwd) (notez bien que l'on utilise pas le $ pour enregistrer ces variables)
        $_SESSION['id'] = $idUser;
        $_SESSION['access'] = $accessUser;

        // on redirige notre visiteur vers une page de notre section membre
        header ('location: index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Is there something I do bad?

Comment: Your code is suspicable to SQL Injection

Comment: first glance - mysql uses `=` not `==`, strings must be encapsulated in quotes `""`/`''`, and php does not parse variables in single quotes only double quotes -> `"SELECT * FROM User WHERE EmailUser = '$user'"`

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` add those two lines straight after `<?php` at the top of the file, retry, and show us the error

Comment: the query also should have quotes around `$user`. And the query is surrounded by single quotes which will not parse variables.

Comment: Also, you are assuming that there will be a match, as you don't account for 0 rows returned from the db, or when the passwords don't match.

Comment: enabling the error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1); doesn't show nothing more.

Comment: Also Changing the to $check = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE EmailUser = '$user'"); doesnt changes nothing

Comment: So its an sql error. And I agree with Jonathans comment, he has pointed out an error

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something I do bad?

Yes.

1) You aren't using parametrized queries.  (Look that up in google)

2) md5 is not a good choice for storing password hashes. see: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.bestpractice